# Facebook user_posts permission: Don't get friends posts/comments from timeline. Just own

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

We have received user_posts permission from facebook.

We also get the posts from the users timeline. But unfortunately only the posts that were written by the user himself and not the posts and comments from friends, which have also written something on users timeline. We tried this with Graph API Explorer 5.0 me/feed.

Does anyone know, if we need more permissions than "user_posts" to get friends posts/comments from own timeline? Or is it not anymore possible to get friends posts/comments from own timeline by API?

user_posts is in "Live mode". But also in "Developer mode" we don't get all posts from a users timeline.

Thank you very much for your experiences and feedback!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v5.0/user/feed#readperms expresses it a bit ambiguously, but I am pretty sure you can only get posts made by users that have granted your app `user_posts` permission themselves. If B posts on A’s feed, then you would get that post when reading A’s feed, _if_ B was also a user of your app and had granted it the permission.

Comment: Thank you for your Feedback. But Facebook doesn't say that friends need "user_posts" permission to view these posts via the Graph API.
I also don't get the posts from friends who have "user_posts" permission. So I still only get my own posts on my timeline. Does anyone have any other idea what might be the cause of this? I am grateful for every idea..

Comment: _“Your app needs user_posts permission from the person who created the post or the person tagged in the post.”_ - you did not say anything about tagging, so this needs permission from the user who created the post then - that is the friend, that posted onto your timeline. And it also says, _“Even with the user_posts permission, it is possible that your app may not be able to read all of a person's posts, or posts that a person is tagged in. Your app's ability to see a specific post must pass several privacy checks, including a person's platform privacy settings.”_